# How can I put a scrollbar in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

**I was wondering how can i put a scrollbar in a pygame window?**

**Please help, Thanks**

Comment: By using code... what have you tried so far?

Comment: come on dude, that's a 2 minute google search....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a pygame built-in method to put a scrollbar on the screen, maybe you must do it by yourself. But if you wanna try it, there is a package named [pygame-menu](https://pygame-menu.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.3/) you can install with pip and import to your project. With this thing you can organize your screen objects using pygame-menu's widgets and if the size of the screen is less than needed to show all the menu's widgets it automatically creates a scrollbar to allow the user to see them.

Comment: Wow. I was 9 years old when I asked this question. And you just answered it 9 years later. My age has now doubled!